# How to refresh Lombok annotation processing in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

Suppose part of annotations are not processed. Below you see `setMinLatitude()` setter is not discovered:

[image]

Simultaneously all getters are seen:

[image]

Building of project works fine, only IntelliJ hits are not up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

For me "Build -> Rebuild project" fix this kind of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **build > Rebuild Project** that will fix your problem

> by the way you can use the annotation `@Getter` and `@Setter` on the
>   class filed and it will generate for all the members in the class

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when I've updated IDEA to a newer version, but the Lombok plugin wasn't automatically updated, and the existing version of the plugin was incompatible with the new version of IDEA.  I didn't notice anything obvious to suggest that the plugin was the issue with annotation processing failures.  Pulling up the "Plugins" settings (`IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences... -> Plugins` on macOS) made it obvious that the plugin was no longer supported and needed to be updated.  Updating the plugin and restarting immediately fixed the issue.

This probably doesn't apply in your case where some of the Lombok annotations are being processed, but will hopefully be helpful for others who have this issue.